# Jena: How to check if an instance belongs to a certain class?

Tags: jena, ontology

Well, sorry for such a naïve question, but I've found no relevant information up to now… I generated `pottery.java` from `pottery.rdf` with [Jena schemagen](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tools/schemagen.html). The properties and classes in my ontology were translated to something like:

```java
public static final DatatypeProperty colors = m_model.createDatatypeProperty( URL_0 );    
public static final OntClass Class_1 = m_model.createClass( URL_1 );
public static final OntClass Class_2 = m_model.createClass( URL_2 );
```

in `pottery.java`.

Say I'd like to list the names and colors of all instances of `Class_1`. How should I do this? All I know now is how to list all instances, whatever which classes they belong to, with the following code:

```java
ResIterator iter = model.listResourcesWithProperty(pottery.colors);
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  Resource r = iter.nextResource();
  System.out.println("  " + r.getLocalName() + " " + 
                     r.getRequiredProperty(pottery.colors).getString() );
}
```

In short, my question is how to add class restrictions into the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether a Resource, `resource`, has a particular RDF type ,`type`, by checking whether it has the property `RDF.type` with value `type`.  If your code above, you can add a conditional of the form:

```java
if ( r.hasProperty( RDF.type, importantType ) ) {
  System.out.println("  " + r.getLocalName() + " " + 
                     r.getRequiredProperty(pottery.colors).getString() );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize this usage of `hasProperty` before.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- `Pottery.java` is the Java class you generated with schemagen, and containing public constants such as `Class_1`, `Class_2`, etc.
- `model` is the `OntModel` containing the RDF data you want to examine

then:

```
// list the resources that are instance of Class_1 in model:
for (ExtendedIterator<Individual> i = model.listIndividuals(Pottery.Class_1); 
       i.hasNext(); ) {
  Individual instance = i.next();
  System.out.println( instance.toString() + " is an instance of Class_1" );
}
```

Edit: I see you also wanted the colours of the instances:

```
for (ExtendedIterator<Individual> i = model.listIndividuals(Pottery.Class_1); 
       i.hasNext(); ) {
  Individual instance = i.next();
  RDFNode cs = intance.getPropertyValue( Potter.colors );
  System.out.println( instance.toString() + " is an instance of Class_1" + 
                      " with colors " + cs );
}
```

See the Jena [Ontology API documentation](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/index.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You're most of the way there:

```
ResIterator iter = model.listResourcesWithProperty(RDF.type, Class_1);
```

will list all things with type (`RDF.type` property) value `Class_1`.

Try the [jena tutorial](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/). You might find the jena ontology api more convenient for this sort of task, but the basic api is fine.